# Conditional regular expression with one section dependent on the result of another section of the regex

Tags: regex

Is it possible to design a regular expression in a way that a part of it is dependent on another section of the same regular expression?

Consider the following example:

`(ABCHEHG)[HGE]{5,1230}(EEJOPK)[DM]{5}`

I want to continue this regex, and at some point I will have a section where the result of that section should depend on the result of **[DM]{5}**.

For example, D will be complemented by C, and M will be complemented by N.

(ABCHEHG)[HGHE]{5,1230}(EEJOPK)**[DM]{5}**[ACF]{1,1000}(BBBA)[CU]{2,5}**[D'M']{5}**

By D' I mean C, and by M' I mean N.

So a resulting string that matches the above regex, if it has DDDMM matching to the section [DM]{5}, it should necessarily have CCCNN matching to [D'M']{5}. Therefore, the result of [D'M']{5} always depends on [DM]{5}, or in other words, what matches to [DM]{5} always dictates what will match to [D'M']{5}.

Is it possible to do such a thing with regex?

Please note that, in this example I have extremely over-simplified the problem. The regex pattern I currently have is really much more complex and longer and ***my actual pattern includes about 5-6 of such dependent sections*.**

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @melpomene: the programming language is really of little importance to me. I am just trying to find the correct 'logic' to do this. I have tried it in R and shell so far. But perl regex is also compatible with R, so that's also in my list. Any programming language is really welcome.

Comment: Well, my answer is in Perl so it's unlikely to work in anything else.

Comment: That's great. I will try it in R (stringr/stringi packages are compatible with Perl regex) and if it does not work I will try it in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like bioinformatics in python. Do 2-stage filtering, at regex level and at app level.

Wildcard the DM portions, so the regex is permissive in what it accepts. Bury the regex in a token generator that `yield`s several matching sections. Have your app iterate through the generator's results, discarding any result rejected by your business logic, such as finding that one token is not the complement of another token.

Alternatively, you might push some of that work down into a complex generated regex, which likely will perform worse and will be harder to debug. Your DDDMM example might be summarized as D+M+, or [DM]+, not sure if sequence matters. The complement might be C+N+, or [CN]+. Apparently there's two cases here. So start assembling a regex: stuff1 [DM]+ stuff2 [CN]+ stuff3. Then tack on '|' for alternation, and tack on the other case: stuff1 [CN]+ stuff2 [DM]+ stuff3 (or factor out suffix and prefix so alternation starts after stuff1). I can't imagine you'll be happy with such an approach, as the combinatorics get ugly, and the regex engine is forced to do lots of scanning and backtracking. And recompiling additional regexes on the fly doesn't come for free. Instead you should use the regex engine for the simple things that it's good at, and delegate complex business logic decisions to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a way you can do this in pure regex. I would run 2 regex expressions. The first regex to extract the [DM]{5} string, such as

`(ABCHEHG)[HGHE]{5,1230}(EEJOPK)[DM]{5}`

And take the last 5 characters. Now replace the characters, for example in C# it would be `result = result.Substring(result.Length - 5, 5).Replace('D', 'C').Replace('M', 'N')`, and then concatenate like

`(ABCHEHG)[HGHE]{5,1230}(EEJOPK)[DM]{5}[ACF]{1,1000}(BBBA)[CU]{2,5}` + `result`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do in Perl:

```
m{
    ABCHEHG
    [HGHE]{5,1230}
    EEJOPK
    ( [DM]{5} )
    [ACF]{1,1000}
    BBBA
    [CU]{2,5}
    (??{ $1 =~ tr/DM/CN/r })
}x
```

I've added the `x` modifier and whitespace for better readability. I've also removed the capturing groups around the fixed strings (they're fixed strings; you already know what they're going to capture).

The crucial part is that we capture the string that was actually matched by `[DM]{5}` (in `$1`), which we then use at the end to dynamically generate a subpattern by replacing all `D` by `C` and `M` by `N` in `$1`.

Comment: This is indeed a very interesting solution. But will this still work if there are several of such dependent strings incorporated into the regex? And more importantly, what if at some point there is a section like [HG]{6,20} and I want to complement it by J and L respectively in a further section of the regex? Will this [HG] not be mixed and confused with the HG's in the [HGHE]{5,1230} section of my regex?

Comment: @lekum I don't see the problem. You just need to define more capture groups and use `$2`, `$3`, etc.